# Is there a way to make it so hunger doesnt go down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to play Minecraft but without the hassle of gathering food. I know I can play in peaceful difficulty, but I want hostile mobs to spawn. Is there a way to get rid of hunger, but still have hostile mobs spawn?

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to commands, you can use

> /effect [username or @a (for all players)] 23 99999 10

Effect number 23 is the effect for saturation. It will replenish your hunger bar. With the power of it being set to 10, it will regenerate half of the whole hunger bar per tick (you can raise it to 20 for the entire bar at a time).

To refresh it, you just need to type in the command again. If you use Command Blocks, you could easily set up a button to do it (if you have access to commands).

Comment: Is it just me or did you copy and paste from the below answer?

Comment: @Angus Atkinson The person below copied from him and plus the information below is wrong about the Xbox 360.

Comment: I am not sure if saturation has a particle effect, but if it does, I suggest adding `false` to the end of the command to suppress them.

Comment: @zombieatmore The other person answered first so therefore could not have copied from this answer.

Comment: When I posted this, the only other answer was Robotnik's. Yesterday as well, I looked at the times, and for about 10  min, mine was at posted 14 hours ago and his was at 13 hours.

Comment: Copied or not, explaining what the command does and generally using coherent grammar makes this the better answer. (Besides, hover over the times and you'll see that this one was first.)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a separate [launcher profile](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_launcher#Time_Machine) to play on a version previous to Beta 1.8, (which is when the Hunger Mechanic was added).

---

Failing this, you may need to install a custom mod. Doing a quick search for disabling hunger in Minecraft turned up a couple of options such as this one:

I've never used them so I cannot tell you how well they work, you will need to test them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you own a server with Multiverse (plugin) you can do `/mvm set hunger false` or back to `true` if you want to. And everyone in the world will not be affected by hunger! Multiverse has a bunch of other cool options like this!